# How to create an Activation process for playing videos

Tags: c#, video, video-player, activation, activation-codes

I am producing course videos for my students and for some reason I have to prevent them to share these videos with one another. I need to create some Activation process in which they can only play videos if they get activation code from me. I have seen something like this before in which video files exist but cannot be played and after activation process they can be played with some custom video player. Do I need to write a custom player? I am .Net developer and wonder if there is any c# solution for this purpose or any other solution.

Comment: what's to stop them sharing activation codes? you can create custom file handlers for IIS that can be used to check the user and a token before returning the file (otherwise returning a 404 or similar)

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Actually activation code is somehow dependent to hardware spec so even they share activation code it does not work. I definitely have some authentication mechanism for downloading files but students know one another and they may share the files. If they have files but not the activation code, as I said they can't play the files.

Comment: How to prevent a student from recording the video using a smartphone and sharing that?

Comment: @thehennyy It doesn't matter, I just don't want them share the actual files.

Comment: so you want to tie the activation code to the actual video file? in that case I'd suggest you look at a DRM solution that encrypts each file and requires a check at playback

Comment: As I said I have seen something like this before. They provided a custom player with video files and they couldn't be played with other players. I think the video files were tied to this player and for running this player we needed to activate with an activator application they provided for us. I don't think they use DRM solution. Something else must be used and I really have no clue :(